# Convert Python Conditional Statement to SQL Conditional Statement?

Tags: python, sql

I am writing a code that inputs a python conditional statement as a string but is supposed to call a function with this conditional statement in SQL format. Does anyone know any straightforward way to convert from a python conditional statement (as a string) to SQL condition (as a string)? Example: "variable1 != 0" to "variable1 <> 0"

Comment: In fact `variable1 != 0` is also valid SQL.  Not sure what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: It appears to me that such a program could make you vulnerable to a [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack and you need to rethink this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.